# Python: How to count pos tags from from a sentence?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, tagging

I have code from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674832/count-verbs-nouns-and-other-parts-of-speech-with-pythons-nltk). It returns the the POS tags along with their occurrence number.
How would I achieve a code where instead of entering a tag I enter a sentence and it returns the words from it and the different pos tags per word based on the corpus (in this case the Brown corpus).

```
def findtags(tag_prefix, tagged_text):
    cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist((tag, word) for (word, tag) in tagged_text
                                  if tag.startswith(tag_prefix))
    return dict((tag, cfd[tag].keys()[:5]) for tag in cfd.conditions())

tagdictNNS = findtags('NNS', nltk.corpus.brown.tagged_words())

for tag in sorted(tagdictNNS):
    print tag, tagdictNNS[tag]

for k,v in tagdictNNS.items():
        new[k] = len(tagdictNNS[k])

print new
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>>from nltk.tag import pos_tag
>>>from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

>>>sent = "This is a foo bar sentence."
>>>text= pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent))
>>>print(text)

>>>from collections import Counter
>>>count= Counter([j for i,j in pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent))])
>>>print (count)
```

Comment: Some comments would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

If it's on English, you can try this:

```
>>> from nltk.tag import pos_tag
>>> from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
>>> sent = "This is a foo bar sentence."
>>> pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent))
[('This', 'DT'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('a', 'DT'), ('foo', 'NN'), ('bar', 'NN'), ('sentence', 'NN'), ('.', '.')]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter([j for i,j in pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent))])
Counter({'NN': 3, 'DT': 2, 'VBZ': 1, '.': 1})
```

NLTK has a built-in module for [word tokenization](http://nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/punkt.html#PunktLanguageVars.word_tokenize) (`nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize` and [POS tagging](http://nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tag.html#pos_tag) (`nltk.tag.pos_tag`) that uses the Penn Treebank tags. Then you can simply input the list of pos tags from the tagged sentence into a `Counter`.

If you want to group the punctuation in a single `PUNCT` tag, you can try this:

```
>>> import string
>>> Counter([k if k not in string.punctuation else "PUNCT" for k in [j for i,j in pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent))]])
Counter({'NN': 3, 'DT': 2, 'VBZ': 1, 'PUNCT': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in [the documentation](http://nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html) (near the very bottom of the page) that may be relevant:

> `nltk.tag` defines several taggers, which take a token list (typically a sentence), assign a tag to each token, and return the resulting list of tagged tokens. Most of the taggers are built automatically based on a training corpus. For example, the `UnigramTagger` tags each word w by checking what the most frequent tag for w was in a training corpus:

```
from nltk.corpus import brown
from nltk.tag import UnigramTagger
tagger = UnigramTagger(brown.tagged_sents(categories='news')[:500])
sent = ['Mitchell', 'decried', 'the', 'high', 'rate', 'of', 'unemployment']
for word, tag in tagger.tag(sent):
    print(word, '->', tag)
```

Which gives:

```
Mitchell -> NP
decried -> None
the -> AT
high -> JJ
rate -> NN
of -> IN
unemployment -> None
```