# Percentage Count Verb, Noun using Spacy?

Tags: pandas, nlp, spacy

I want to count percentage split of POS in a sentence using spacy, similiar to

[Count verbs, nouns, and other parts of speech with python's NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674832/count-verbs-nouns-and-other-parts-of-speech-with-pythons-nltk)

Currently able to detect and count POS. How to find percentage split.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import spacy,en_core_web_sm
from collections import Counter
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
print Counter(([token.pos_ for token in nlp('The cat sat on the mat.')]))
```

Current output:

```
Counter({u'NOUN': 2, u'DET': 2, u'VERB': 1, u'ADP': 1, u'PUNCT': 1})
```

Expected output:

```
Noun: 28.5%
DET: 28.5%
VERB: 14.28%
ADP: 14.28%
PUNCT: 14.28%
```

How to write the output to pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import spacy,en_core_web_sm
from collections import Counter
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
c = Counter(([token.pos_ for token in nlp('The cat sat on the mat.')]))
sbase = sum(c.values())
for el, cnt in c.items():
    print(el, '{0:2.2f}%'.format((100.0* cnt)/sbase))
```

Output:

```
(u'NOUN', u'28.57%')
(u'VERB', u'14.29%')
(u'DET', u'28.57%')
(u'ADP', u'14.29%')
(u'PUNCT', u'14.29%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines should give you what you need:

```
sbase = sum(c.values())

for el, cnt in c.items():
    print(el, '{0:2.2f}%'.format((100.0* cnt)/sbase))


NOUN 28.57%
DET 28.57%
VERB 14.29%
ADP 14.29%
PUNCT 14.29%
```