# Counter calling in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I want to call counter values inside pandas.

Effort so far:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import spacy,en_core_web_sm
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
c = Counter(([token.pos_ for token in nlp('The cat sat on the mat.')]))
sbase = sum(c.values())
for el, cnt in c.items():
    el, '{0:2.2f}%'.format((100.0* cnt)/sbase)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(c, orient='index').reset_index()
print df
```

Current Output:

```
   index  0
0   NOUN  2
1   VERB  1
2    DET  2
3    ADP  1
4  PUNCT  1
```

Expected Output:

The below inside dataframe:

```
(u'NOUN', u'28.57%')
(u'VERB', u'14.29%')
(u'DET', u'28.57%')
(u'ADP', u'14.29%')
(u'PUNCT', u'14.29%')
```

I want to call el and cnt inside the data frame how?

It was a folow up question wherein i wanted to get percentage of POS distribution listed.

[Percentage Count Verb, Noun using Spacy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51685224/percentage-count-verb-noun-using-spacy)

I was of understanding I need to put group el and cnt in place of c below:

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(c, orient='index').reset_index()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only fix your out put since I do not have the original data

```
(df['0']/df['0'].sum()).map("{0:.2%}".format)
Out[827]: 
0    28.57%
1    14.29%
2    28.57%
3    14.29%
4    14.29%
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: `(df.iloc[:,1]/df.iloc[:,1].sum()).map("{0:.2%}".format)` @Programmer_nltk

Comment: @Programmer_nltk check it again , I adding the `.`